# anti distraction app - block website using traffic filter - choice of method

Tags: .net, web, filtering, block, firewall

I want to create my own anti distraction software for windows (windows 2k, XP, Vista, 7). It should block websites by traffic filtering, thus hosts file is not an option.

Creating a proxy sever application is also possible, but that would demand telling every application to use it. Furthermore, the user could just change the system proxy settings. Thus this is not an option.

Researching here I found out that there are several remaining options:

1.) using http://www.winpcap.org
2.) NDIS intermediate driver
3.) using windows firewall rules: example of a low level driver http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/93087-firewall-dll/

Since several people were interested in this, it would be great if an expert could answer the following questions for non-experts

a) are there other options 
b) are there aother low level drivers or example vb projects like 3.) that use firewall rules and works on all windows versions?
c) which of these methods can most easily be implemented using MS .NET framework

thanks a lot

Comment: sorry I am quite new hear and at the beginning have often failed to specify my questions in enough detail

Comment: would be glad if somone could give expert comments... thanks